# Newly created JButton doesn't override the previously created JButtons

Tags: java, image, swing

Essentially, what I have coded is a puzzle game.

It contains an image , and the image is further divided into 9 pieces which is placed onto JPanel containing a 3x3 JButton GridLayout. Initially, the 9 buttons are empty. When the user clicks "Start Game", the 9 buttons will then show the images on the buttons.

I used setPreferredSize() to set the size of the JPanel containing the 9 empty JButtons. After that, I used Inset ( 0,0,0,0 ) to make the button's contents fill the entire button.

But now, when I want to add the imaged buttons to replace the empty buttons when the user clicks "Start Game" , it doesn't work.

I think this is because the `setPreferredSize()` I set earlier on is preventing the `Insets` values from working.

I inserted some `system.out.println` values to check if the method is running, it runs, but the image still refuses to appear on the buttons when user clicks "Start Game" .

```
    public class GameFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        private JButton button1;
        private JButton[] button = new JButton[9];
        private Insets buttonMargin;
        private boolean testImageMethod;
        private JPanel puzpiece;

        public GameFrame(){
            //.. coding ..

            // create new buttons - button1
            button1  = new JButton("Start Game");
            // add action event to "Start" button
            button1.addActionListener(this);

            // creates a new panel for the splitted puzzle pieces
            puzpiece = new JPanel();
            puzpiece.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

            // check if testImageMethod boolean ( in setupImage() ) is true, 
            //if it isn't, adds 9 buttons w/o images.
             for(int a=0; a<9; a++){
                 if(testImageMethod){
                 }
                 else{
                     // adds 9 buttons without images 
                   button[a] = new JButton();  
                   puzpiece.add(button[a]);
                   puzpiece.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));
                 }


             }
             // adds puzpiece panel into the frame 
              this.add(puzpiece,BorderLayout.WEST);     
            //.. coding ..

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == button1){
                // puzpiece.button.setVisible(false);
                //puzpiece.remove(button);

                // call setImage() method
                setImage();

                for(int a=0; a<9; a++){
                // adds the new 9 buttons with images into panel
                puzpiece.add(button[a]);
                // test if method is running
                System.out.println("qq");
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("bbb");
            }
        } 

        // method setImage() divides the image into subimages
        public void setImage(){
          //.. coding ..
          // test if method is running
          System.out.println("a");

            setupImage( count++, sc );
        }

        // method setupImage() adds the subimages to the buttons
        private void setupImage( int a, Image wi )
        { 
          // test if method is running
          System.out.println("d");

            buttonMargin = new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
            button[a] = new JButton( new ImageIcon( wi ) );
            button[a].setMargin( buttonMargin );

            // test if method is running
            System.out.println("e");

        } // end method setupImage()
    }
```

Comment: Why replace JButtons? Why not instead simply swap ImageIcons displayed by the JButtons?

Comment: Please check the edit to @GagandeepBali's answer. He has provided some nice clean sample code illustrating his points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I know exactly what you're doing but, ...

- It appears that you are populating a JPanel with a 3x3 grid of plain JButtons,
- and that on button press you are adding in JButtons that display an image.
- But I don't see you removing the original buttons before adding new buttons.
- Nor do I see you call `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the puzpiece JPanel after changing components.
- And even more importantly, why swap JButtons when it's much easier to swap ImageIcons in JButtons that are already held by the puzpiece JPanel? This is something that I recommended in comment 10 minutes ago but am now making an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yup, what you said mirrors what I wanted to do. I tried calling revalidate() and repaint() in a previous trial and error but it created additonal buttons instead of overriding the original 9 buttons :O

Answer (score 4):

Simply `setIcon` for the said `JButton`, don't add `JButton` anew to the `JPanel`, already visible

A small example for the same :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Gagandeep Bali
 * Date: 1/19/13
 * Time: 10:05 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class ButtonImageTest
{
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private JButton button;
    private int counter = 1;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Button Image Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton();
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (counter % 2 != 0)
                {
                    button.setIcon(errorIcon);
                    counter = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    button.setIcon(infoIcon);
                    counter = 1;
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonImageTest().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, exactly as I stated in my comments made earlier.1+

Comment: Nice detailed example code! I will leave a comment to the OP to review this as he may not have yet seen it.

Comment: Nah, it's okay, it's basically I just added for the future visitors, your answer had got every detail OP is looking for :-) Thankyou though for appreciating the answer :-)

Comment: What's the purpose of @override for the actionPerformed method ?

Comment: It tells the compiler that you are actually overriding some method of the super class, so if you have committed some spelling mistake while defining the method, the compiler can check for all the methods in the super class to compare with yours, to warn you that this method is not overriding any method of the super class. In the absence of `@Override` , (considering you have spelled the method wrong while overriding )the compiler will treat this wrongly spelled method, as any other method of the class, and won't generate any error.

Comment: Thus, even though you think that you are overriding a method of the super class, but in actual terms you spelled it wrong, hence it is treated as an ordinary method of the class, which you never called. Try to change the name of the actionPerformed(...) (do not add @override), the error from the compiler might will tell you the benefit of the same. Now try to keep the wrong spellings for `actioNPerformed(...)` and use `@Override`.